# Creating word definitions using HTML

Tags: html, css

I'm wondering if any HTML tag exists to create lists from example 1 instead of example 2:

[image]

Is this `ul`/`ol` element with `b` tag inside? Or maybe `dl`, `dt` and `dd`? I'm sorry if this is too easy question but I really have no idea. Technically, according to W3 specification, it can also be `figure` element but none of these will produce this nice indentation. Does this require CSS? If so, what kind of CSS?

References:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-blockquote-element
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element
- http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/grouping-content.html#the-dl-element

Comment: This certainly requires CSS. Visual browsers hardly use non-CSS implementations to render HTML these days.

Comment: As far as I know, `<dl>` stands for "dictionary list".

Comment: @BoltClock Good point. With all these answers here I already know everything.

Comment: @Álvaro G. Vicario: Historically it stood for "definition list", while now it stands for "description list".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you've posted there is a classic use for a definition list (`<dl>`). Here is another way you could do it:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
  dl, dt, dd {margin:0; padding: 0;}
  dl {width: 300px;}
  dt {float: left;}
  dd {overflow: hidden; padding-left: 14px; position: relative;}
  dd:before {content: "-"; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 4px;}
</style>

</head>
<body>
  <dl>
    <dt>code</dt>
    <dd>a system for communication by telegraph, heliograph etc., in which long and short sounds, light flashes etc. are used to symbolize the content of a message ...</dd>
  </dl>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, this works and it's a valid HTML for this purpose :) I'm still trying to figure out how did you do this. It looks like a clever solution.

Comment: Using `overflow: hidden` along a float uses a thing called [block formatting context](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/05/19/css-101-block-formatting-contexts/). Though a useful trick, the explanation is an advanced CSS topic to say the least

Answer (score -1):

maybe with css like this ?

```
ul
{
  list-style-type:none;
  width:400px;
}

li
{
   float:left;
}
```

markup

```
<div>
<ul>
    <li>
        code - 
    </li>
    <li style="width:200px;text-align:justify;">
        adofjsdofioijdfoidjgdoigjgoidjgdofgjdfogidfjgoidfgjdfiogjdiogjdf
        dfgoijfdoigjdgoijgoigjoigjgoidjgoidfgjdfoiigjfdoigjfdgoidfjgoidfjgi
        dfgdgdjgodifgjdoigjogijgoigjfdoigdfgodfgoidfjgi
    </li>
</ul>    
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NB2Ep/12/

There maybe better ways to do it. I used simple ul/li.